# InteliJ and Tomcat Server Interworking 500 Error Solution

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat9

I linked Tomcat with IntelliJ and it keeps getting 500 error. The problem is that there is a problem in the 22nd line, can you solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFVlA.png)

I've tried a lot of things to solve by myself but I'd like to get advice from people who are way better than me.

Comment: Click the link in the console to see the Maven error.

Comment: `I've tried a lot of things` What were those things exactly?